# How to solve "Index exceeds matrix dimension" in segmentation process (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, save, image-segmentation

I've modified my code for segmentation process. But I get an "Index exceeds matrix dimension" error. The code is as follows.

```
for z = 1: 300
    name1 = strcat ('data (',int2str(z),').png');
    name2 = strcat ('D:\1. Thesis FINISH!!!\Data set\0 Isolated Dataset\Advertising Bold 14\source\', name1);

    a = imread (name2);

myFolder = 'D:\1. Thesis FINISH!!!\Data set\0 Segmented Character\coba';
%% Binarization %%
level = graythresh (a);
b = im2bw (a, level);

%% Complement %%
c = imcomplement (b);

%% PadArray %%
i=padarray(c,[0 10]);

%% Vertical Projecttion for Character Segmentation
verticalProjection = sum(i, 1);
set(gcf, 'Name', 'Segmentation Trial', 'NumberTitle', 'Off') 
subplot(2,2,1);imshow(i); 
subplot(2,2,3);
plot(verticalProjection, 'b-');
grid on;

% *Defining the threshold to determine baseline area* % 
threshold=max(verticalProjection)/3;
% threshold=min(verticalProjection)/3;
% threshold = 5; % Threshold >0 used to detect the baseline of cursive characters 
thresholdedProjection=verticalProjection > threshold;
count=0;
startingColumnsIndex=0;
for j =1:length(thresholdedProjection)
    if thresholdedProjection(j)
        if(count>0)
            startingColumnsIndex=startingColumnsIndex+1;
            startingColumns(startingColumnsIndex)= j-floor(count/2);
            count=0;
        end
    else
        count=count+1;
    end
end
endingColumns=[startingColumns(2:end)-1 j-floor(count/2)];

% *Extract each region, result of segmentation process* %
y=1;

for k = 1 : length(startingColumns)
    % Get sub image of just one character
    subImage = i(:, startingColumns(k):endingColumns(k)); 
    % im = subImage;
    s = subImage;

    % Normalization using algorithm 2 %
    p = normalization2 (s);

    subplot(2,2,2); 
    imagesc (p); 
    axis equal off;
    pause (1); 
%   figure, 
    imshow (p);

    % Morphological Operation - Thinning %
    t = bwmorph(p,'thin',Inf);  
end

% savename = char (strcat (myFolder, name1));
imwrite (t, fullfile (myFolder, sprintf ('data.%d.png', y)));
y = y+1;
end;
```

I have 300 word images data, and I need to segment all of the images' data into character images and save them as different files for each segmented characters. I need to save it sequentially.

I've already try to change

```
subImage = i(:, startingColumns(k):endingColumns(k));
```

to

```
subImage = i( startingColumns(k):endingColumns(k),:);
```

But it still didn't work.  I have no idea what's wrong with the code.  Can anyone please explain and help?

Comment: In which line are you getting the error?

Comment: Hi Troy, ||

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

|| Error in segmentt (line 64)  ||
    subImage = i(:, startingColumns(k):endingColumns(k));

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change the `k` in `endingColumns(k)` on line 64. From the code it does not seem like `startingColumns` has the same number of elements as `endingColumns`.

Comment: Yes, I think it is. That's why it's not helpful.
|| So, what do you think I should change in the code, to resolve the error?

Comment: `k` should not exceed the `end` of `startingColumns`. Try adding a condition like that.

Comment: `endingColumns=[startingColumns(2:end)-1 j-floor(count/2)];` it has the same number of elements as `startingColumns`. isn't it true? `endingColumns` has same values from (1:end-1) as `startingColumns` has from (2:end) and `endingColumns(end) =j-floor(count/2)`. So aren't the number of elements same?

Comment: Is it?
in this simulation, I check at the workspace, endingColumns value = [30,42,58,76,62] || while startingColumns value = [7,31,43,59,77,64], it doesn't give the same number of elements.

Comment: If you can debug step by step, it should help.

Comment: I've already get the answer and the segmentation already running well. I just add startingColumns = []; to initialize startingColumns.
||
I want to share it, just in case there are people who meet the same problem.
||
Thank you all...